# Extend the backgroung-image on a <li>

Tags: html, css, background, html-lists

I have some unordered list, and made it so it shows up a background image on the li if the cursor is hovering it:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
/* I DON'T HAVE STYLE FOR <UL> */
.sidebar li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.sidebar li:hover {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url(../img/mbg.png);
    color:white;
}
```

But it looks like:

[image: odd li]

How can I make the background reach to the end on the left? Thanks!

Comment: can you add the li and ul style also

Comment: added li style, no style for ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you have to write like this:

```
.sidebar li{
margin:0;
pading-left:10px;
}
```

then it's work 
check this http://jsfiddle.net/2thVU/

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with `.sidebar li:hover`
Check jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CrMZM/) **(Same css is working fine)**